# .js files not being served to development server

Tags: javascript, html

My html file references a .js file in a `static` folder which is a different directory from the `.html` file directory (templates). when i run the `.html` file, it works fine as the `.js` files are loaded.Problem is,if i run the app in the local server i get the error message:

```
 GET http://localhost:63342/UniteMessageBoard/templates/%5CUniteMessageBoard%5Cstatic%5Cjquery.js   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
```

and the script does not load.

**This is my `html` code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="\UniteMessageBoard\static\jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\UniteMessageBoard\static\script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
<input type="button" id="submit2" value="get it">
</body>
</html>
```

**and my `script.js` code:**

```
console.log('loaded script.js');

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#submit2").on('click', function (event) {
    handleClick();
});

});


function handleClick() {
  alert("We got here");
    $.ajax('/', {
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        fmt: 'json'
    }
 });
 }
```

**and the `main.py` code:**

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
autoescape=True)



class MainHandler (webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):

    self.templateValues = {}
    self.templateValues['title'] = 'jQuery JSON Tutorial 2'
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/base.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(self.templateValues))


  app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   ('/.*', MainHandler)

   ], debug=True)
```

This is the error code i get if i run the app locally:

```
 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 18ms]
```

even though it doesn't actually load.

**Edit:**
This is my directory tree:

[image]

Comment: Make the slashes forward. Nobody uses backslash for directories anymore.

Comment: Believe it or not,that's the only way it works if the html file is in the templates folder.If it's outside the templates folder, `/static/jquery.js` works just fine but with the same problem am having.

Comment: Ok… can you post your directory tree?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that too but it still doesn't work.@bjb568 i have update the question.Please take a look at it.

Comment: As UniteMessageBoard is your root, with `index.html`, you shouldn't need the `UniteMessageBoard` part in the src. So, try `src="/static/jquery.js"` The / makes it root-based, so the root of your site, which **is** `UniteMessageBoard`

Comment: The problem is with the `base.html` file.Am trying to reference the scripts from the templates folder.

Comment: _“Am trying to reference the scripts from the templates folder”_ – resolution of relative URLs for embedded external resources is done by the _client_.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost certainly developing on a windows box. I can tell because of the `\` instead of `/`. The problem is that your web server running on localhost wants those to be `/`. So, accessing the file locally, without passing through a web server it works, but once you get to a server it breaks.

Comment: you should only use `/` for file paths, and you should only view your pages through the web server.